Postgresql Logical Replication from citus distributed table to another citus distributed table
I followed this guide (https://docs.citusdata.com/en/stable/develop/integrations.html) to implement logical replication of the "items" table between two postgres db. On DB1 the "items" table is distributed using the citus extension (1 coordinator + 2 worker nodes), on DB2 the citus extension is installed but the "items" table is not distributed (single node).
In detail: On DB1 I created the items_pub publication:
CREATE PUBLICATION items_pub FOR TABLE items;

and then I created the replication slots:
SELECT * FROM run_command_on_all_nodes(
   $$ SELECT pg_create_logical_replication_slot('cdc_slot', 'pgoutput', false) $$
);

On DB2 I created the subscriptions:
create subscription sub
   connection 'host=10.100.100.37 user=user dbname=DB1 password=password port=5432'
   publication items_pub
   WITH (copy_data=true,create_slot=false,slot_name='cdc_slot');

create subscription sub_1
   connection 'host=10.100.100.38 user=user dbname=DB1 password=password port=5432'
   publication items_pub
   WITH (copy_data=false,create_slot=false,slot_name='cdc_slot');

create subscription sub_2
   connection 'host=10.100.100.39 user=user dbname=DB1 password=password port=5432'
   publication items_pub
   WITH (copy_data=false,create_slot=false,slot_name='cdc_slot');

Everything works perfectly and every event of INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE on the items table of DB1 is propagated correctly to the items table of DB2.
The problem arises when I transform the "items" table on DB2 into a distributed table via Citus. (again with 1 coordinator + 2 worker nodes). At this point any event coming from DB1 is not received by DB2. I have tried several solutions without success. I would like to understand if what I am trying to implement is possible or not and if possibly there are other solutions.

Did you have a chance to look at the Postgres logs on the publisher and subscriber nodes?

The logs from the subscriber simply report:
"the logical replication application worker for subscription sub_XXX has started"
Publisher side no relevant events are reported in the postgresql log.

I noticed wal segments are properly sent from DB 1 worker nodes to DB2 worker nodes. But when I read wal segments on DB2, related for examples to 1 INSERT, I see:
NEW_CID -
INSERT off -
INSERT_LEAF -
INVALIDATION - ; inval msgs: catcache 62 -
COMMIT
what is the meaning of INVALIDATION statement?
